# .index() inside .each() always return 0 when checkbox array in a table or div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me with this issues.

i'm going to get the index number of checked **checkbox** array which reside in a html table, but each time i alert the each of **checkbox's** index inside .each() , its will return 0 for each loop.

*but this code will work if i remove the table and all its tr and td (leave the two checbox alone)*

**my jquery code:**

```
function notify() {

               $("input[type = 'checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
               alert($(this).index());  /*always return zero when the check[] inside a table or div */                
               });           
           }

function main() {


        $("input[type = 'button']").click(notify);
}


$(document).ready(main);
```

**my html code:**

```
 <table>
   <tr><td>
    <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' />
   </td><td>
   <input type='checkbox' name='check[]' />
   </td> </tr>  
 </table>   
<input type='button' name='button' value='ok'/>
```

[this is the link to my code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuNE6/)

Comment: `.index()` without arguments returns the position of the node among its own siblings. And in every `<td>` your checkboxes are the first (and the only) ones - so you're getting `0` See http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: Good reason why this problem arise..i will study  to find another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for. SInce you are wrapping your check boxes in td's, why not find the index of td

[[Demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/xgS9P/)

```
function notify() {

    $("input[type = 'checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        alert($(this).parents('td').index());
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..finally..thanks alot..for my case i need to add the td parrent.  alert($(this).parents('td').parents('tr').index());

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index,value){
          alert($(this).parents('td').index());  
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cuNE6/9/

Comment: still not working..the problem arise when the checbox[] elements in different td..if i remove the td, it works.

Comment: its working only when two the checkbox is ticked..but if only one checkbox is ticked, their always show 0 even though the 2nd checkbox is ticked.